# C# : Draw Lines on top of Image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am filling Grid with image that I Draw Programatically.

Now, I want to draw lines(Horizontal and vertial) on top of the Image. After adding Image to the grid as children, I want to draw lines. How can I do this ?

```
var image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image
        {
            Source = DrawImage(products),
            Width = options.OutputWidth,
            Height = options.OutputHeight
        };

        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.Children.Add(image);
```

Comment: Just add the lines again to the Grid's children with a higher z-index.. this should cause them to overlap the image

Comment: Have a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10cf8826-dbbb-472b-9c4a-1d2f8db0545f/draw-over-image-in-wpf?forum=wpf).

Answer (score -1):

The image class extends FrameworkElement,so you can extend the image class and add ur drawing logic on OnRender(DrawingContext dc) method.

```
public class CustomeImage:Image{
protected ovveride OnRender(DrawingContext dc){
 dc.DrawLine(//line location and pen here)
}
}
```